# how to use Two CollectionViewCell in the same CollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to use two `CollectionViewCell` in the same `CollectionViewController`.

Can you help me please ?

thanks

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)indexPath.row + 1];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: how you want to use both cell in collectionview ? can you explain your functionality ?

Comment: In fact, I would like to create a news feed like Facebook. the first UICollectionViewCell it's for "Stories" and the second UICollectionViewCell it's for the user's post.

Comment: like odd and even ? if yes then below answer will works for you

Comment: I had to go wrong trying. I do not know how to try the code below. I start on Xcode. I am a beginner

Comment: `if (indexPath.item % 2 == 0) { write your "Stories" cell code} else { write your "user's post" cell code}`

Answer (score 0):

Give each cell type a unique reuse identifier and, if necessary, a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. In your `cellForItemAtPath` function, use the identifier to get the one that's appropriate for the path, e.g.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.item % 2 == 0) {
        EvenCollectionViewCell *cell = (EvenCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: "evenCell" forIndexPath :indexPath];

        // Configure the cell
        ...

        return cell;
    } else {
        OddCollectionViewCell *cell = (OddCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: "oddCell" forIndexPath: indexPath];

        // Configure the cell
        ...

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: @pilou write your "Stories" cell code in if condition and write your "user's post" cell code in else condition